# Python interactive video

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am in the process of developing stimuli for a psychology study. Currently, I am trying to figure out how to display a pre-recorded video that will respond to viewer inputs. I would like to do this in python, but I am open to other open source options if the benefit outweighs the learning curve.

**Here are the basic materials I am working with:**

Video A - a complete video, also the default video
Video B - the alternate video that will be spliced in upon input from USB controller
USB controller - a hand-held USB controller that participants will use

**Here is the basic idea:**

viewers will be told that they are watching a webcam feed (Video A) and that they need to make a decision by either pressing or not pressing a button on a USB control. If they choose not to press the button, the video will continue to completion. However, if and when they press the button, video B will be spliced in, such that the "web cam feed" appears to reflect their decision. Importantly, upon USB input, the screen will flash white for approximately 1 second and a sound effect audio file will be played, obscuring the splicing in of video B.

**Here is what needs to happen under the hood:**

Display video from file 
Make video screen flash white upon USB input
Play audio file upon USB input
Load video B upon USB input/after white screen

**Here are some parameters I would like to satisfy:**

I'd like to do this in python 3.4+ 
If it would not be too much more difficult, I would like to setup a simple GUI interface to increase the plausibility of the alleged webcam stream

**My questions:** I have just started learning python, and I am using version 3.4. I have looked at several different packages, including OpenCV, however I am really not sure about how to go about assembling these tasks. If anyone can recommend a set of packages that would enable me to build this program, link to a tutorial or set of tutorials that would help me along my way, or provide specific input on this project, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

The opencv site is great for a beginner in opencv and I have personally been using it in my computer vision project (I too am new to computer vision though not coding). It's nicely organized, and for the most part has everything you could need.

I would personally stick with opencv as it's the number one opensource computer vision api out there. Another great option would be matlab (though I have never used it and it is proprietary). They have a free 30 day trial or something like that. It might be worth a shot to look at. I've heard it is extremely easy to use.

As far as getting feedback from a usb controller, I know opencv provides functions for mouse feedback. I've currently got my project set up so that on a mouse click, a single frame is captured from a live video feed. I imagine there's a way to do this with your specific device and what you've described actually sounds fairly doable in a short amount of time. Just go through the tutorials, specifically the GUI Features section and I think you'll find most of what you need.

On a side note, I don't believe you can use python 3.4 with opencv as it only supports up to 2.7.

What ide are you using and on what os? Also, have you installed everything on your computer?

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. At the time of posting, I had not yet installed opencv, but you convinced me to give it a try. After a considerable amount of troubleshooting, I have gotten it to work. I am using PyCharm on Ubuntu 14.04. I have also been working through opencv's website, which, as you noted, is quite helpful. Thanks for your thoughts.